# Is it possible to generate an accurate high frequency wave by turnin an I/O port high and low?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, wave, atmega

I want to generate 3 , 1MHz waves with 100ns difference in phase ! is it accurate to generate them with OC mode ?
I mean i can do it by increasing the OC , 3 times with little steps and 4th time with a big  step , and continue this , and in each ISR toggle an I/O port ( a total of 3 i/o ports are being toggled) 
but my question is if this process is accurate ?! or there are some clock which are being lost in this process ?!

Comment: If you are using timers, then nothing's lost.

Comment: are you sure about this ?!

Comment: @userXXX I absolutely am.

Answer (score 0):

No. However OC generated waveform is exact itself and is independent of execution of your program, it is not true for the delay.
Just think of statement length. However most of statements are 1 cycle long, some of them are longer and interrupt may not occur in the middle of a multicycle statement.
The OC based timing is different, it is performed by timer hardware so it may happen even in the middle of a multicycle statement.
To summarize the answer: your primary waveform will be correct, but the delayed will jitter.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look in the PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) feature of your microcontroller. You may be able to use that to set these waves up: even if you need to run them by different timer units, since the timers may be clocked by the same source (the oscillator of your micro), you may have means to sync them this manner.

100ns is a very short time. You need a 10MHz oscillator to be able to tick this. If your micro can execute one op per cycle, and you want to tick it out directly, then you would need to toggle the three pins in consequent instructions (all taking 1 cycle each). This is possible, but needs very careful design. Interrupts and such are out of question for ticking the 100ns, however you may utilize them in a clever way to schedule the pin change task. How you could do this depends on what you exactly want to achieve.

(I once had to steal data from an 1,5MHz micro's bus with a 40MHz PIC which did one op in 4 cycles, which data was sample-able for just 300ns. I could budge it and the thing worked fine - so this pin change business is certainly possible as well, just needs **very** careful design)